# Android Studio - Gradle build running never ends

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, debian

I just installed Debian 8 in my PC. I tried to set-up Android-Studio(1.4):

- Downloaded from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Unzip in /opt
- Downloaded the SDK and everything

When I try to create a new project, and also if I open an old project, it gets stuck building (I let it running for more than 1 hour and it never ends).
In console it always prints:

> $ android-studio/bin/studio.sh  Tooling API is using target Gradle
>   version: 2.4. Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent
>   builds will be faster). Starting process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java''. Working directory:
>   /home/tobias/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication Command:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version Successfully
>   started process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' Starting daemon
>   process: workingDir = /home/tobias/.gradle/daemon/2.4, daemonArgs:
>   [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m,
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant, -cp, /opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.4/lib/gradle-launcher-2.4.jar,
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon, 2.4,
>   /home/tobias/.gradle, /home/tobias/.gradle/daemon, 10800000,
>   4f46addb-22d0-418f-8179-49ef885a95cc, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m,
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant] Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory:
>   /home/tobias/.gradle/daemon/2.4 Command:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.4/lib/gradle-launcher-2.4.jar
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.4
>   /home/tobias/.gradle /home/tobias/.gradle/daemon 10800000
>   4f46addb-22d0-418f-8179-49ef885a95cc -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon' An attempt to start the daemon
>   took 1.354 secs. Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=4668,
>   address=[d3bdeeea-46b5-40d0-8eaf-ab113cda06ce port:33671,
>   addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false,
>   context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=4f46addb-22d0-418f-8179-49ef885a95cc,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/tobias/.gradle/daemon,pid=4668,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}.
>   Dispatching request Build{id=d764db2d-9d61-4582-8c7c-ba0d7d68ca22.1,
>   currentDir=/home/tobias/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication}.

I have tried re-installing and restarting, and nothing.

Comment: r u got answer. I have same issue bro.

Comment: You can try if it helps to set the gradle into offline work mode from the settings of android studio. I don't know if it will help on linux, but it fixed a similar problem I had with Windows version. If you want to try, you can click: File -> Settings... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Check Offline work. After this click "Apply" and restart your android studio.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by the a 32bit library requirement even with 64bit systems.

See this post [missing dependencies android SDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk)
The discussion is around eclipse, but the same issue applies to android studio.

If you are using Fedora this should fix your problem and help you avoid some other problems.
Fedora version <= 21

```
yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686
```

Fedora version > 21

```
dnf install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686
```